# Find a word between double quotes and replace it with suffix using regular expressions in notepad++

Tags: regex, string, replace, notepad++

I have a file with text as below. I would like to find the word between double quote (i.e., TABLE_NAME_1) and replace that after adding suffix (i.e, _test) to the original word.

Sample data from a file:

```
<TableName Value="TABLE_NAME_1" />
<TableName Value="TABLE_NAME_22" />
<TableName Value="TABLE_NAME_333" />
```

Expected data:

```
<TableName Value="TABLE_NAME_1_test" />
<TableName Value="TABLE_NAME_22_test" />
<TableName Value="TABLE_NAME_333_test" />
```

I tried like below. But this adds the suffix at the end of the line instead of just before the last double quote.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

*Find What*: `<TableName Value="[^"]*\K`
*Replace with*: `_test`

Here, `<TableName Value="[^"]*\K` matches `<TableName Value="`, then zero or more chars other than `"` (with `[^"]*`) and then `\K` omits the text matched so far. Thus, the `_test` is added to the empty string just before the trailing `"`.

See demo screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @ Viktor,  how does the `\K` in the end works?  Since this discards everything till last position, and how can the `OP` accept and upvote your answer, your answer doesn't work at all, but we can correct it in a captured group,  like this ↦ `(<TableName Value="[^"]*)` and replace with `$1_test`

Comment: Or may be  `<TableName Value=\K("[^"]*)`

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah See [Keep The Text Matched So Far out of The Overall Regex Match](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) to learn more about `\K`.